Neighbouring cover in a directed graph
I am not sure if this type of problem has been studied before, so it would be great to receive some guidance. Consider a directed graph G=(V,E). We define an in-neighbourhood cover as a subset $W\subseteq V$ so that $\forall v \in V, \exists w \in W$ with $(w,v) \in E$. In plain words, I want to be sure that at last one "in-neighbour" is in $W$. We can assume that the problem is feasible, i.e., that at every node has at least one in-neighbour. Similar to other covering problems, the idea is to find the smallest such $W$, or the one with the smallest weight if every node has a weight.
Do you know if this problem has been studied, and if so, if it is NP-Hard?
Thanks for your help!

These are dominating sets https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominating_set

I just proved that we can find such a set with size $\leq\left\lfloor\frac{N}{2}\right\rfloor$ some time ago https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4932189/1099603
